# Redhat DHCP Server issues IP by not validating mac address

Tags: rhel, dhcp

I have kickstart setup on a Redhat satellite server. On the dhcp server, I added a redhat1 to be kickstarted; while the redhat1 getting built, the dhcp server issued redhat1's IP address to a unknown host (a Windows server). This is causing the redhat1 server to have an incomplete build. What is causing the dhcp server to issue redhat1's IP to a second server?

```
# more /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
option domain-name "build.local.com";
option domain-name-servers 10.10.3.9, 10.10.3.8;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 10.10.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option routers 10.10.3.1;
        range 10.10.3.80 10.10.3.85;
}

host redhat1 {
        hardware ethernet 00:50:56:B7:7A:4D;
        fixed-address 10.10.3.83;
}

allow booting;
allow bootp;
next-server 10.10.3.90;
filename "/pxelinux.0";
#
```

Here are the /var/log/messages file entry for the IP 10.10.3.83

```
/var/log/messages-20150927:Sep 23 14:42:01 satellite dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.10.3.83 to 00:50:56:b7:7a:4d via eth1
/var/log/messages-20150927:Sep 23 14:42:05 satellite dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.3.83 from 00:50:56:b7:7a:4d via eth1
/var/log/messages-20150927:Sep 23 14:42:05 satellite dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.10.3.83 to 00:50:56:b7:7a:4d via eth1
/var/log/messages-20150927:Sep 23 14:42:12 satellite dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.3.83 from 00:50:56:b7:7a:4d via eth1
/var/log/messages-20150927:Sep 23 14:42:12 satellite dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.10.3.83 to 00:50:56:b7:7a:4d via eth1
/var/log/messages-20150927:Sep 23 14:44:14 satellite dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.10.3.83 from 00:50:56:b7:18:a5 (windows) via eth1
/var/log/messages-20150927:Sep 23 14:44:14 satellite dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.10.3.83 to 00:50:56:b7:18:a5 (windows) via eth1
```

Comment: According to the thread at https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2008-December/007658.html, giving a host a `fixed-address` doesn't prevent the address from being assigned to anyone else if mentioned in a `range` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, did the windows box formerly have a lease on `10.10.3.83` by chance (the `dhcpd.leases` might indicate this)? Not sure what is going awry otherwise, as I keep any `fixed-address` assignments outside of any addresses listed in `range`.

Comment: I see `10.10.3.83`, previously leased to windows box. To make it simple I removed the `range` from `dhcpd.conf` file. I re-built server, looks good now.